# What steps should I take to investigate comment is not displaying immediately with meteorjs and reactjs

Tags: reactjs, meteor, meteor-react

I have comment section where people can talk and currently when I post comment, I have to refresh a page to see my new comment.

I’m really new to meteor so I’d like to know what steps should I take to invest this behavior.

client-side

```
const CommentList = ({ cardId }) => {
  const query = useMemo(
    () => ({
      $or: [
        { commentType: COMMENT_TYPE.smsComment },
        {
          $and: [
            { commentType: COMMENT_TYPE.cardComment },
            { createdAt: { $gte: System.getChatCommentsDate() } }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }),
    []
  );

  const isCommentsLoading = useSubscribe("card.comments", cardId);
  const comments = useFind(
    () =>
      CardComments.find(
        {
          cardId,
          ...query
        },
        { sort: { createdAt: 1 } }
      ),
    [cardId, isCommentsLoading()]
  );

  const memoizedComments = useMemo(
    () =>
      comments?.map(({ _id, userId }) => <Comment key={_id} commentId={_id} />),
    [comments, reporterId]
  );

  return <>{isCommentsLoading() ? <LoadingIcon /> : memoizedComments}</>;
};
```

serverside/publication

```
Meteor.publish(
  'card.comments',
  (
    cardId,
    query = {
      commentType: {$in: [COMMENT_TYPE.cardComment, COMMENT_TYPE.smsComment]},
    },
  ) => {
    check(cardId, String);
    check(query, Object);
    return CardComments.find(
      {
        cardId,
        ...query,
      },
      {
        sort: {createdAt: -1},
      },
    );
  },
);
```

So far, I read an article about useSubscribe and useFind
https://blog.meteor.com/how-to-use-meteor-with-react-hooks-7e1791daabab

I made sure after I hit a submit comment button, comment is store in a database.

Also I looked at the meteor extension on chrome and Subscriptions tab. I see card.comments is subscribed.

in Minimongo tab, I only see three card_comments documents existing. but I have 8 comments displayed on the screen.

After I submitted the comment, I see nothing happens in DDP tab.

What do you expect happening here? or what else can I do?